# Max date with Google output

Tags: javascript, date, google-apps-script

With each email thread, I'm using the `.getLastMessageDate()` and producing an array that looks like this `[Mon Nov 14 05:58:24 GMT+08:00 2016, Thu Nov 17 07:46:01 GMT+08:00 2016, Tue Sep 27 07:00:06 GMT+08:00 2016, Wed Sep 07 10:46:50 GMT+08:00 2016, Sun Jul 31 18:47:16 GMT+08:00 2016, Sat Jul 09 06:14:15 GMT+08:00 2016, Sun Apr 24 20:33:50 GMT+08:00 2016, Sun Apr 03 11:48:40 GMT+08:00 2016, Thu Mar 31 12:55:39 GMT+08:00 2016, Wed Mar 23 06:59:00 GMT+08:00 2016]`

My question is how to figure out what's the latest date? This would be easy in Python, but I think in this case, each element is a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
var dates = ['Mon Nov 14 05:58:24 GMT+08:00 2016', 'Thu Nov 17 07:46:01 GMT+08:00 2016',
             'Tue Sep 27 07:00:06 GMT+08:00 2016', 'Wed Sep 07 10:46:50 GMT+08:00 2016',
             'Sun Jul 31 18:47:16 GMT+08:00 2016', 'Sat Jul 09 06:14:15 GMT+08:00 2016',
             'Sun Apr 24 20:33:50 GMT+08:00 2016', 'Sun Apr 03 11:48:40 GMT+08:00 2016',
             'Thu Mar 31 12:55:39 GMT+08:00 2016', 'Wed Mar 23 06:59:00 GMT+08:00 2016'];

var max = dates.reduce(function(a, b) {
  return new Date(a) > new Date(b) ? a : b;
});
// max should contain the latest date as a string.
Logger.log(max);
// Thu Nov 17 07:46:01 GMT+08:00 2016
```

Comment: You are hoping that the Date constructor will correctly parse the provided string format, but it's not one that is required to be supported by ECMA-262. Support is implementation dependent and should not be relied upon.

Comment: Fair point. It does work on Apps Script, however, which is the target.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the dates like this:

```
var dates = [
  "Mon Nov 14 05:58:24 GMT+08:00 2016", 
  "Thu Nov 17 07:46:01 GMT+08:00 2016", 
  "Tue Sep 27 07:00:06 GMT+08:00 2016", 
  "Wed Sep 07 10:46:50 GMT+08:00 2016", 
  "Sun Jul 31 18:47:16 GMT+08:00 2016", 
  "Sat Jul 09 06:14:15 GMT+08:00 2016", 
  "Sun Apr 24 20:33:50 GMT+08:00 2016", 
  "Sun Apr 03 11:48:40 GMT+08:00 2016", 
  "Thu Mar 31 12:55:39 GMT+08:00 2016", 
  "Wed Mar 23 06:59:00 GMT+08:00 2016"
];

dates.sort(function(a, b) {
  return new Date(b) - new Date(a);
});

alert(dates[0]);
```